# Can't Kill xls files

Tags: vba, excel, kill

I have been using every version of Kill routines to delete xls files in the current directory with no success.  Here is my code.  I want to delete every xls file except wbCntl.  Stepping through this code shows that everything works with the exception of the Kill swb command. (swb is public defined as a string)

```
    'Close all files except wbCntl
        swb1 = wbCntl.Name
        For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
            swb = wb.Name
            If swb <> swb1 Then
                Workbooks(swb).Close SaveChanges:=False
                On Error Resume Next
                Kill swb
                Err.Clear
            End If
        Next wb
```

Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the Name property is just the file name. The Kill method requires the full path. Try using the FullName property instead.

Also you can run into weirdness when you delete an item out of a collection you are iterating through using "For Each". Try this:

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim lngIndx As Long
    Dim strFilePath As String
    For lngIndx = Excel.Workbooks.Count To 1& Step -1
        strFilePath = Excel.Workbooks(lngIndx).FullName
        If strFilePath <> ThisWorkbook.FullName Then
            Excel.Workbooks(lngIndx).Close False
            SafeKill strFilePath
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub SafeKill(ByVal path As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill path
End Sub
```